# Let's improve our [software-design]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

The tag [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) (1528 questions) has a lot of low-quality and off-topic questions, many of them asking for software or asking "can someone help me" on a vague software design problem.

Could we implement better [software-design] and clean up this tag?

Comment: Do we even need to have it at all? It smells like a meta tag to me.

Comment: This tag should be burninated.